# Why there is a difference between the accuracy of sklearn.LogisticRegression with penalty='l1' and 'l2' and C=1e80?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, regularized

I am somewhat disappointed by the results I am getting. I create two models (`sklearn.linear_models.LogisticRegression`) with `C=1e80` and `penalty = 'l1`' or `'l2'`, and then test them using `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score` with `cv=3` and `scoring='roc_auc'`. To me, `C=1e80` should result in virtually no regularization, and the AUC should be the same. Instead, the model with `'l2'` penalty gives worse AUC, and multiple runs give me the same results. How does this happen?

Comment: is your data normalized? Scale of C is strongly correlated with scale of features

Comment: Could you post a code and possibly a data sample?

Comment: Thank you, @lejlot. Normalization really resolved this issue. I didn't think it matters that much in the cross-validation case...

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it a bit more clear. The general form of most loss functions is

```
C SUM_i=1^N loss(h(x_i), y_i|theta) + regularizer(theta)
```

thus the whole problem with `C` is to find a balance between sum of losses over training samples and regularizer value.

Now, if loss is bounded (like in the case of logistic regression), then without proper normalization L2 regularizer (||theta||^2) may grow to infinity, thus you will need very high C to make it irrelevant and thus equal in solution to L1 (max_j |theta_j|). Similarly if you have loss which grows very fast, such as Lp loss for p>=2, then regularizer might be very small thus you will need very small `C` to make it do anything.